# PHP move_uploaded_file local path

Tags: php, apache, upload, alias

Is it possible to add a local destination to method `move_uploaded_file`?  example `C:/foo/`

I want to upload files, but store them outside the root folder, and use an alias to access the new destination.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I do not think that the user apache able to write outside the space reserved for his virtualhost!

Comment: As long as the server daemon user has access to the destination path, you should be able to write to it.

Comment: @JellyBelly..it's possible show my answer, you can do that

Comment: @ViralShah: but one must take into consideration the fact that if you do not have a dedicated server is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the definition:
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )

In $destination you can put any valid path.
Be sure the directory security allows for writing for the user that webserver runs as.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. As I had the alias `bar` to point to my `C:/foo/` path, in the PHP code I was adding `bar` to the `$destination` parameter.

It works if I set the parameter `$destination` to `C:/foo/`